# Is that a coincidence or sophisticated attack

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security

today I experienced very strange network behavior. I was at work and as always I was connected to my home server with Outlook Web App. The connection dropped and I was not able to connect. I got home and found, that it's problem with router ASUS RTN56U. I have two routers, one main as internet gateway and secondary, for guests. And I have switch between first and second router, which was not affected. Because the ASUS was not working (unable to connect to management, no internet connection), I decided to configure guest TP-LINK to be main router. It worked, but there was 70% packet loss. Simply the secondary router is also out of order. And previously, worked fine. When I connected my PC directly to provider (without router) it was absolutely OK.

I borrowed another TP-LINK (the third one) and now my network works perfectly. It is very strange, that two routers came into sillicon heaven in the same time.

Was my network compromised? What other scenario can lead to this situation?

Edit: One more fact, which goes me into suspection of attack: When I disconnect router from WAN, they behave normally - I'm able to connect their web management. When I took ASUS back to standard configuration, it returned to bad state. Also, the voltage scenario is not probable, because there's other devices connected to same electric circuit (like a switch) and they were not affected anyway.

Edit 2: In affected routers, the network behaves very bad, but you can see the WAN LED control trying to explode...

Comment: Strange is, that both my routers of different vendor were probably infected with same kind of malware. Strange is, that if it was malware, why it disrupted my network? Too many questions. They were not sending SPAM as I checked blacklists and they're OK. Option is that they were DDoSing someone. As vonbrand wrote, today network truants tries to stay hidden. Well I removed the vulgar sentece, what other text of me you consider as offensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, impossible to know with *much* more details (and perhaps a forensic analysis of the machines). And that is a huge amount of work, probably not worth it. Besides, it might be a non-coincidence (e.g. a voltage spike fried both, or the failure of one somehow broke the other).

In any case, today's network truants are *very* careful not to disturb the systems (too much), they want to rummage for passwords or credit card numbers, or just use your resources to send spam or mount attacks on third parties.